# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''leave''

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I always get this error when i run my code

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''leave'' at line 1

Here is my coding part

```
<?php
        $result = mysql_query("select * from 'leave'");
        if ($result == FALSE)
        {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href = "app_status.php? id = <?php echo $row["Leave_ID"];?>" target = "_blank"></a>Leave ID</td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Emp_ID"];?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $row["Date_Apply"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Leave_Type"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Leave_Start"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Leave_End"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["Status"];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: is leave is your table name?

Comment: Don't put 'leave' in quotes, assuming that `leave` is the name of the table.

Comment: **Never use quotes around column names.**  They are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea as well, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: @AndyLester perfectly agree on the part about not using reserved keywords as table or column names! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use single quaots

You can try it as

```
 $result = mysql_query("select * from leave");
```

Or use ` key

```
 $result = mysql_query("select * from `leave`");
```

Comment: Its better as `"SELECT * FROM \`leave\`"`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes i agree

Comment: There is absolutely **no reason** to put the table name in quotes.  None.

Comment: Thanks for helping guys. I had solve my error. I appreciate it.

Comment: @AndyLester Except when the table name is a reserved keyword, then you need to enclose the name in back quotes. [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/leave.html)

Comment: Or, don't use a reserved word as a table name, which is the far more sensible option.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from 'leave'");
                                   //^     ^
```

Use backtick character ` for table name:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from `leave`");
```

Answer (score 0):

possible answers:

1) Any values which are not numeric will need to be quoted.

2) Your input data should be cleaned/escaped too before use. You are currently open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from your_db.leave") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (id),` I got this error.

I think we can't use 'order' as the table name (I think it's a keyword). I had to use 'order_and_contracts' instead.